# Headers not showing on apache camel rest services

Tags: rest, http-headers, apache-camel

I am trying to set headers to response of rest service that i am creating. I am able to set the body but when i set the headers, it is not showing on soap ui.

Here is how i am trying to set body and headers:

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("SERVICE-VERSION", "1.0.0");
exchange.getOut().setHeader("MESSAGE-PROTOCOL", "NONE");
exchange.getOut().setHeader("RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "JACKSON_JSON");
exchange.getOut().setHeader("OPERATION-NAME", operationName);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
exchange.getOut().setBody(mapper.writeValueAsString(beanClass));
```

As i said earlier, i can see the body as response but none of the above headers are set on the response.

Please suggest how to go about the above problem. Looking forward to your solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you include your route as well?

Comment: Thnaks for the reply boday. I solved it myself. i just had to convert to jaxrs Response with headers.